# Таймер текста как реализовать

Tags: python

Как добавить таймер? Чтобы после ввода 'получить текст' появляется текст - print('text') через 1-3 секунды? Идей нету, так как опыта должного нет. Вот сам код

```
    a = input()
    if a.lower() == 'получить текст':
        print('text')
        b = input()
        if b.lower() == 'получить инфо':
            print('info')
        else:
            print('error')
    else:
        print('error')
    
    >>> получить текст
    text
    получить инфо
    info
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import time

a = input()
if a.lower() == 'получить текст':
    time.sleep(3)
    print('text')
    ...
```